# Has the cardinal of the real set minus a subset of it the same cardinal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cardinals

I have to check the cardinal of $\bar{A}$(The complement of A) where

$A = \{ 1 \le x \le 2 \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

I thought that a good idea would be to argue it by demonstrating that $\bar{A} \subset \mathbb{R}$ but I think that this is not really mathematical. Can this be correct? In case it isn't where can I find some propierties of cardinal related with $\aleph_1$?

Comment: Look for an explicit bijection $A\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Oh, you should explain that your bar is the complement, not the closure.

Comment: @MikhailKatz you are right, I edited

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with alef-1 issues.

Comment: Incidentally, $\aleph_1$ is **not necessarily** the cardinality of the reals: that's $2^{\aleph_0}$, and [they may not be equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) (although many texts make the mistake of conflating them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open interval $(1,2)$ is equinumerous with $\mathbb R$ by using the function $\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-2}$.  Thus $A$ is equinumerous with a subset of $\mathbb R$ and vice versa.  A general result of Cantor allows you to conclude that they are equinumerous.

Similarly, the open interval $(2,\infty)$ can be put into 1-1 correspondence with $(1,2)$ (or with $\mathbb R$ itself) by a suitable rational map. Then a subset of the complement of $A$ is equinumerous with a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and vice versa, and we conclude much as before.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:** Whenever we have a subset $A$ of an infinite set $X$ and an injection from $A$ to its complement $X\setminus A$, then $X\setminus A$ has the same cardinality as $X$.

Proof: Obviously we have
$$|A|+|X\setminus A| = |X|$$
which because $X$ is an infinite set means $|A|=|X|$ or $|X\setminus A|=|X|$. So if $|A|<|X|$ the claim follows immediately. On the other hand, because of the injection we have
$$|A|\le |X\setminus A|\le |X|$$
which for $|A|=|X|$ again implies $|X\setminus A|=|X|$ $\square$

Now $\mathbb R$ clearly is an infinite set, and an injection from $A$ to its complement is given e.g. by $x\mapsto x+2$. Therefore the complement of $A$ in $\mathbb R$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.